# How to use particular function in node js in file A to file B with port connection in one file

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I need to use getStatus() function in file A to file B.

File A:

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(5002);

function getStatus(){
 // other code
}

module.exports = {getStatus}
```

File B:

```
const {getStatus} = require('./fileA')
```

But when I use **require** in fileB I am getting an error

```
address already in use :::5002
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: There is another process that uses this port 5002 ,change it in FileA

Comment: there is one more process executing when we use require in file B I am asking how to change

Comment: I am running File A at the start and and when I am importing in file B it is executing again so 5002 error is coming I know that But I to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

Move the function to file C and require it from both. Otherwise any top level code, including the listen call, will potentially run more than once and you will get the port conflict. This is why libraries typically don't do anything at all at top level except export functions for you to call when and if you are ready.

Comment: I need to use some variables in file A in that function so I need to use in file A only.

Comment: Then you need to pass those variables to the function when you call it. Always inject dependencies.

Comment: Are these two separate programs? Are you trying to get the real time status of one program from the other?